# Javascript and PHP in harmony - Search function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently constructing a "datatable"-ish search function.
When a user inputs something into a search box, I'd like to update the div containing its values.

Currently I do this using this input field:

```
<input type="text" id="IdSearch" onkeyup="Search()" value="<?php echo $searchtext; ?>" onfocus="this.value = this.value;" name="zoeken" autofocus>
```

The `onfocus="this.value = this.value;` makes sure the selector is behind the values after the page is reloaded.

```
<script>
    function Search() {
        var x = document.getElementById("IdSearch").value;
        window.location.href = "index.php?search" + x;
    }
</script>
```

And then

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $searchtext = $_GET['search'];
    echo $searchtext;
    $sql = "SELECT blabla FROM blabla";
    //execute sql statement and update the table now..
} else {
    //generate the standard table
}
```

This works, it outputs a correct result, but it's sluggish. The page needs to reload every time you input a character.

So maybe, just maybe, I can somehow retrieve the searchbox' value every time a key pressed, and update my table that way?

I know PHP runs and then doesn't run again without a page reload. Maybe I can reload certain elements? I don't know.

Please, don't go all "PHP runs on the server" on me. I know, that's why I'm currently using this method. I am not even going to attempt to learn ajax in the timespan I have to finish this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Maybe I can reload certain elements?" — That is, more or less, what Ajax is, so if you aren't willing to learn it, you can forget it.

Comment: "More or less what ajax is".. Yes, i know. You can eat ravioli with a spoon, but if you'd rather eat it with a fork, it's there. I'm looking for a fork. I hope my analogy is not to vague

Comment: Your analogy is wrong. You are trying to eat ravioli without eating a type of dumpling composed of a filling sealed between two layers of thin pasta dough.

Comment: Clearly it's not about the ravioli, but what you try to eat it with. The ravioli is my php output, the spoon is ajax, the fork is some kind of revolutionary javascript function. I don't even like dumplings anyway.

Comment: You need AJAX and some form of debounce (look up lodash debounce) on that `keyup` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not even going to attempt to learn ajax in the timespan I have to finish this.

I'm afraid you'll have to either learn AJAX or submit to using iFrames. If you are going to use AJAX, there's some great libraries out there ([JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/), or maybe [qwest](https://github.com/pyrsmk/qwest)) that make it super easy to learn, quickly.

> Maybe I can reload certain elements?

Yes! The other option, using [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) is pretty strongly frowned-upon by the web developer community as a whole, but it does exactly what you ask for. Check out MDN's information about [scripting iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting). You can use the same properties as you do on `window` now, but it will still probably be sluggish and most likely quite annoying to work with as well.

**So,** if you want my advice: use AJAX. But it's your choice!

Comment: Ajax it is. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 0):

-Either you use a **button** " " to submit the search....
and remove the onkeyup="Search()"

```
<button type="submit">Search</button>
```

-Or you can try to **post** your form **into an Iframe**.... but still will be **sluggish**.

-The way to go is **AJax** : dynamically update the content while type-in.

Comment: Then I guess Ajax is the only real way. Do you think I can use Bl00dsoul's answer without really editing the  code/knowing what it does?

Comment: To learn ajax is not difficoult.... If I have time I will post an example for you.... in the menatime you can use any someone else code or even better learn on the web...

Answer (score 0):

- use AJAX (like $.ajax) and create a php response in json. then recreate your content with a javascript template or an MVVM framework like angular.
- Another way is return the part of the content than you need and inject with $('#mycontent').html(response).

Answer (score -1):

try jquery `$.post` it's everything you're looking for.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Maybe as a last resort.. As I said, I don't know any ajax code, and I'd rather not use code I don't understand. If it isn't possible in any other way, I'll look into it.

Appreciate the answer.